# How to change the timezone of the date of an order in the backoffice?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I want to show the date of an order in another time zone.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Backoffice UI (zk framework) automatically convert timezone to user browser timezone. If user has correct timezone in his OS, browser automatically use it. If you need to use timezone different then user browser, search zk framework sources for overriding it (I think it is not good option).